# How can I instruct curl to reuse credentials after it followed a redirect?

Tags: authentication, redirection, curl

I know that `curl` can follow redirects (the `-L` argument), and I know that I can provide credentials to a request (`-u username:password`), but I want to use both all the way down the redirect chain.

How can I tell `curl` to reuse the username and password on every redirected location?

Comment: This would be useful to me..did you get a solution?

Comment: Btw i discovered wget can do this, but still have not figured out how to do it with curl..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the [`--location-trusted`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--location-trusted) option:

> allow sending the name + password to all hosts that the site may redirect to.

The libcurl option for this is `CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH` and it is available from curl version 7.10.4-pre6 (31 Mar 2003).

Comment: epic `man curl` overlook happened...

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2008-11/0067.html, the `--anyauth` argument could be a solution.

Comment: I read this entry, but it is not the same problem. That HTTP request have multiple redirects,and one of those will ask for username and password,and asks if `curl` can use the provided credentials **only** when the webserver requests it. What I want is to instruct `curl` to use the credentials on **every** redirected URL. This might sound stupid, as there is no guarantee that every site uses the same credentials, but these sites are under my control and I set the same user/pass on them. (I am testing a desktop website, and wanted to check if it properly redirects if the UA is mobile)